# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Titanium.Network.online') after MobileIron integration

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, mobileiron, appcelerator

I am facing problem in MobileIron integration with Appc code. The code work fine with out MobileIron code.

After MobileIron I am getting error like this

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Titanium.Network.online')

Ti.Filesystem also same issue. first I commented this code. Next line we have online checking logic. There also it say object undefined.

Any idea on this, please help me.

Comment: We solved this problem in different way rather  just creating module by adding  MobileIron Appconnect Framework to of project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem in different way rather just creating module by adding  MobileIron Appconnect Framework to project. We used reflection concept in module code and wrapped app with Appconnect App wrapper. It worked for us.